# help me understand the transformation into polar coordinates from a differential-geometric view

Tags: differential-geometry, polar-coordinates

I'm not entirely familiar with viewing differential equations from a differential geometry viewpoint.

As far as I understand it, in terms of differential geometry, polar coordinates are a 2-dimensional manifold over the set $ M = \mathbb{R}_{>0} \times \mathbb{S}^1$.

One way to define a topology on $M$ would be to take all the disks
$$
D_R = \{(r, \theta) \in M : r < R\}\\
\mathcal{D} = \bigcup_{R\in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}} D_R. 
$$

There exists one global chart $(U, \varphi)$ with $U = M, V = \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$ and $\varphi: U \to V $, usually called the "polar coordinate transformation" map a point $p = (r, \theta)$ on the manifold to coordinates $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$
$$
x^1 =r \cos(\theta)\\
x^2 = r \sin(\theta),
$$
which necessarily (as a chart) is continuous and invertible and the inverse is defined on $\varphi^{-1}: V \to U$.
(I understand, that if I prove additional properties of this chart, like e.g. smoothness, then that shows $\mathcal{M}$ to be a smooth manifold.)

Let us call $\mathbb{R} = (R, \mathcal{O}, \mathcal{A})$ the standard manifold on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with default topology and an atlas consiting only on the identity.

For my current problem, I am given a first oder differential equation defined by a vectorfield $\{\xi(x)\}_{x\in \mathcal{R}}$ in terms of (coordinate functions **?**)
$$
\xi(x) = \begin{bmatrix}\xi^1(x)\\\xi^2(x)\end{bmatrix},
$$
as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}^1\\
\dot{x}^2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\xi^1(x)\\
\xi^2(x)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now unfortunately, the component function of $\xi(x)$ are not "nicely shaped" and make it hard to state precicely some properties I am after.
So what I did was taking the inverse $\varphi^{-1}$ of the aforementioned chart and taking the time derivative, the subsequently substituting in $\varphi^1(p), \varphi^2(p)$.
My differential equation now looks like this:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{r}\\
\dot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
f^1(p)\\
f^2(p)
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

**Now, in the terminology of differential geometry, what did I do here?**

Moreover, $\mathcal{R}$ can be endowed with a norm as a metric, so that I can show $\xi(x)$ to be Lipschitz, which is direly needed for the existence of solutions.
However, I need to be able to check the Lipschitz property directly in polar coordinates.

**Am I getting the terminology right so far?**

**Can somebody guide me how I should proceed to understand this?**

Comment: Cartesian and polar coordinates aren't usually thought of as different *manifolds*; They're typically treated as different *coordinate charts* for the same underlying manifold $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Interesting, but I'm not conviced. Following your comment, the polar coordinates are a mapping for the manifold $\mathbb{R}$ to $M$. All definitions I know require chart maps to be a mapping to subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: The coordinate chart associated with polar coordinates is the map$$(r,\theta):U\to\mathbb{R}^2$$where $U\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is an open set on which polar coordinates are well defined.

Comment: No, the map you described is not a chart map, because the inverse 
$$
\varphi^{-1} : \mathbb{R}^2 \to U
$$
is not a bijection. You would have to restrict the image of the chart map to be something like $(-\pi, \pi] \times \mathbb{R}$, but this is exactly the reason why I started to view the polar coordinates as a manifold.

Comment: I'm using the definition that a chart is a map $\varphi:U\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the image of $\varphi$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\varphi$ is a homoemorphism onto its image. If you prefer, you can restrict such a chart to its image.

Comment: Okay, that's exactly the definition I am using. And my objection had exactly to do with the *homeomorphism* part. For the homeomorphism  we need it to be a bijection, so I'd very much like to restrict the chart to
$$
\varphi: U \to V, U \subseteq M, V := \operatorname{image}_\varphi(U) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2.
$$
I need to think about your comment for a bit, then probably update the question.